# Django multiple selection field

Tags: django

I am using django-MultiSelectField to do a multiple choice field where multiple check marks are allowed. How would I render this in the django template?

```
choices =   (('0', 'option info...'), 
             ('1', 'another option...'), 
             ('2', 'more options info...'), 
             ('3', 'option info...'), 
             ('5', 'none of the above'))
class questions(models.Model):
    questions_base = models.OneToOneField(base, primary_key=True)
    questions5 = MultiSelectField(choices=choices, max_length=1)
```

I will submit it into the namespace for the template in views.py before I render it. I am thinking that I should use some html like this:

```
{% for choice in all_choices %}
<div class="col-lg-6" for='questions5'>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <input type="checkbox" aria-label="..." value='choice'>
    </span>
    <label type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">Hello world</label>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I know this is a bit sloppy, but you get the gist

Comment: you will need to provide much more information than that: lets see your model, view and template code.

Comment: The [github page](https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield) shows how to do the model. That is how I did it... I need to know how to do the HTML so that I can just throw the request.POST into a form and save it

Comment: What you want to do is use a form class. And then render that.